# Switching a readonly stream to a writable stream

Tags: c#, stream

I am making an api call using a 3rd party sdk which returns a readonly stream.

```
var mystream = await.client.getDataStream(params);
```

The same sdk is being used to upload that data (to a different destination) and accepts a stream. The problem is that when I use the same stream I get an exception.

```
await.client.uploadDataStream(params,mystream); //throws exception
```

I am quite confident that the reason is due to the fact that the stream itself is a readonly stream. If I take that stream, write it to a file and then stream the file as the upload stream it works perfectly fine.
But I don't want to do that.

Is there a simple way to copy the stream to a new stream without writing to a file and without the destination being readonly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried copying it to a MemoryStream?

Comment: yes....tried something like this    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
         myStream.CopyTo(memStream);  but I still get the exception. Only if I write to file and read does it work?

Comment: You need to reset the stream read position after the copy (memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) ) before you can use it as a source.

Comment: `throws exception` what exception?

Comment: @SteveTodd resetting the copied stream worked like a charm, thanks!